# Does adding S->SS in a context-free grammar change the language to its Kleene star?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, kleene-star

Let $L$ be the language generated by a context-free grammar whose start variable is $S$. Does adding $S \rightarrow SS$ in this grammar creating language $L^*$, why? What about grammars in Chomsky normal form?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Mind the empty word.

Answer (score 6):

As [chi](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/43599/chi) pointed out in the [comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/93071/does-adding-s-ss-in-a-context-free-grammar-change-the-language-to-its-kleene-st/93083?noredirect=1#comment200809_93083), since $\varepsilon\in L^*$ and $\varepsilon$ may not belong to the new grammar, so adding $S\rightarrow SS$ does not always generate $L^*$. It makes more sense to ask whether it generates $L^+$, so the following answer focuses on $L^+$.

---

## General Form

Consider the following grammar:

\begin{align}
S&\rightarrow aSb\\
S&\rightarrow \varepsilon
\end{align}

It generates the language $L=\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Now after adding $S\rightarrow SS$ in this grammar, the string $aababb$ can be generated by the grammar but it does not belong to $L^+$.

## Chomsky Normal Form

Easy to see $L^+$ can be generated by the new grammar. Now for any string $s$ generated by the new grammar, we can prove $s\in L^+$ by mathematical induction on the depth of its parse tree. Consider the derivation process of $s$.

If the first derivation does not use the rule $S\rightarrow SS$, we can conclude $S$ does not show up in the following derivation since $S$ does not show up in the right hand side of a CFG of Chomsky normal form. As a result, $s\in L$.

If the first derivation uses the rule $S\rightarrow SS$, the strings generated respectively by the two $S$'s in the right hand side must belong to $L^+$ due to inductive assumption, thus $s$, which is formed by concatenating the two strings, also belongs to $L^+$.

Comment: The last proof only proves that $L(G \cup \{S\to SS\}) \subseteq L(G)^*$. The converse inclusion looks false, in general, e.g. when $G=\{S\to a\}$.

Comment: @chi Isn't $L(G)^*=\{a\}^*\subseteq L(\{S\rightarrow SS, S\rightarrow a\})$?

Comment: No, since $\{a\}^* \not\subseteq \{a\}^+$. I think the only issue here is the empty word, and that using $L^+$ instead of $L^*$ should fix everything. So, I'm being a bit pedantic here :-P